# Looping Pipe operator in R

Tags: r, deep-learning

Im currently building a deep neural network in R using keras.  Everytime I want to add a layer to my network I have to manually add it in, as follows:

> model %>%

```
      layer_dense(units=5,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4))%>%
      layer_dense(units=5,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4))%>%
      layer_dense(units=100,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4))%>%
```

However, if I want arbitrarily large networks, this is not convenient.  Is there a way to "loop" over the pipe operators?  That is, if I specify the depth I want can I build a loop which adds layers up  to that amount?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's pretty straightfoward:

```
model<-keras_model_sequential() 

for(i in 1:Depth){   
model %>%
    layer_dense(units=5,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4)) %>% 
    layer_dense(units=Height,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4))
}   

model %>% layer_dense(units=1)
```